# Cannot wildcard search "member" in openLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

.
I have an odd problem, where I cannot seem to use wildcard searches for the "member" or the "uniquemember" attibutes for a group.

Consider the following:

```
cn=myusers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass=groupOfNames
objectClass=top
```

This returns fine:

```
ldapsearch -h ldap-server -p 389 -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w Password -s sub -b "ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" "(objectclass=groupOfNames)" member

cn=myusers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
member=cn=user1234,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

And if I use this, it also works fine:

```
ldapsearch -h ldap-server -p 389 -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w Password -s sub -b "ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" "(&(member=cn=user1234,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)(objectclass=groupOfNames)" member
```

But, suppose I want to find all the groups, with member names that start with "user". I try this:

```
ldapsearch -h ldap-server -p 389 -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w Password -s sub -b "ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" "(&(member=cn=user*)(objectclass=groupOfNames))" member
```

But nothing returns!

Now I have tried adding indexes to the "member" and "uniquemember" attibutes as:

```
member pres,eq,approx,sub
uniquemember pres,eq,approx,sub
```

... but get a returned error of 'additional info: approx index of attribute "member" disallowed', so I was left with:

```
member pres,eq
uniquemember pres,eq
```

Even after the change, I still cannot perform wildcard searches using "member" or "uniquemember" attibutes. Any ideas?

.

Answer (score -1):

This works as expected with the [UnboundID Directory Server](https://www.unboundid.com/products/directory-server.php). Try updating the directory server software - there are some similar questions on the OpenLDAP forums where this problem was resolved by a fix to DN normalization.

Also, there is no such thing as a 'wildcard' search. The assertion value to which you refer results in what is called a 'substring' search. For increased performance, the server should index the `member` and `uniqueMember` attribute values for substring (`sub`), assuming the legacy OpenLDAP server supports indexing those attributes for substrings.